# PHP Encoding - UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

With cURL, I am saving files which have UTF-8 chars in the filename.

For example:

```
testšć.docx
```

When I used `mb_detect_encoding()`, it returned ASCII.

So I tried to convert it with `iconv` from ASCII to UTF-8 and from UTF-8 to UTF-8.

Neither option worked.

**So does anyone has a suggestion on how I could keep UTF-8 file names?**

Cheers!

Comment: make sure the php file is encoded in UTF8 if you are doing an output of the data and try using utf8_encode to convert to the proper encoding (http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: Show the piece of code that calls `mb_detect_encoding`. What are you calling `mb_detect_encoding` *on* exactly? Also note that `mb_detect_encoding` is not really an exact science and you hardly need it if you *know* what encoding you're dealing with.

Comment: @Dany Khalife
i fetch file name which has UTF-8 chars from website.
like that: $h1 = $html->find('h1',0)->plaintext;
then I just use file_put_contents but it doesn't save properly.

deceze
I just used it once to saw what encoding is parsed text encoded in.

Comment: ok i see what you mean, any chance we can have a look at the piece of code that fetches your data and saves them? (That way we can try it ourselves..)

Comment: @DanyKhalife sure

$html = str_get_html($data);
$h1 = $html->find('h1',0)->plaintext;

$dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project\\'.$h1; 

mkdir($dir);
// its almost identical as i posted above.When I try to create directory it has strange chars in there.So any suggestions?
Btw for own testing you can try to fetch char from http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ and create folder with it

Answer (score 1):

Your file system (and operating system) must support UTF-8 encoded file names in order to retain files that use UTF-8 in the file name. If either do not support that, then the best option is to either convert them into a known transliteration, or discard (replace) the characters that cannot be converted.

Comment: im curious to know which FS or OS doesn't support UTF8

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) is a list on Wikipedia of filesystem limitations.

Comment: In short, not many. I could be entirely misunderstanding your question though.

Comment: @JoshuaK
My filesystem does support it, because if I type with my keyboard it works ok.But problem is once I parse UTF-8 filename from website like that: $h1 = $html->find('h1',0)->plaintext;

Answer (score 0):

In analogy with MySQL, when your MySQL data is encoded in UTF8 you should have php read it through a UTF8 "communication" so since your HTML data is in UTF8 i think your problem is (tho i don't have all your code to know if im correct) that you are not reading it as UTF8

Try adding this option to your cURL config:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );
```

I don't know if this IS what you are missing, but in case not let me know and i'll update my answer...